# javascript multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm trying to define a multidimensional object in JavaScript with the following code:

```
function A(one, two) {
    this.one = one;
    this.inner.two = two;
}

A.prototype = {
    one: undefined,
    inner: {
        two: undefined
    }
};
A.prototype.print = function() {
    console.log("one=" + this.one + ", two=" + this.inner.two);
}

var a = new A(10, 20);
var b = new A(30, 40);
a.print();
b.print();
```

The result is:

```
one=10, two=40
one=30, two=40
```

, but I expect

```
one=10, two=20
one=30, two=40
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is a variable `inner` a class variable, not an instance?

JavaScript engine: Google V8.

Comment: When thinking in JavaScript don't think in terms of `instance` think in terms of `scope`.

Comment: @Hogan, good point.  It's important to remember that while JS has structures that look like classes, they're really first-class objects and need to be treated as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the object literal for `inner` gets shared for all instances.  It belongs to the `prototype` and thus every instance shares the same object.  To get around this, you can create a new object literal in the constructor.

Comment: +1 : but could you please show the code to create the new object literal?

Comment: Basically the same thing just needs to be done in the constructor.  `this.inner = {two: two};`

Comment: Yes, it solves my problem. But in this case, the code becomes less documented.

Comment: @ZeroDivisi0n, I see what you're saying, you could maybe move such an initialization to a init() method if that might help with documentation.  It appears you're coding with class concepts, whereas JavaScript doesn't have classes.  Your `prototype` at this point could just be `A.prototype = {}`.  Think of using the `prototype` for stuff that you want to share between instances.  Thus, you shouldn't look to it for exhaustive documentation of your "class" and every property that can exist on it. The constructor or init() function may be the best spot for listing these all out.

Answer (score 1):

The `inner` part is a global object not bound to one instance.